# error copy file that was created in C#

Tags: c#

I have this problem when I try to copy a file that was created in C#:

"System.IO.IOException: 'The process can not access the file' d:\las.txt 'because it is being used in another process.'"

my code:

```
using System;

namespace modulo1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string folderName = @"c:\lasss";

           System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);

           string archivo = @"d:\las.txt";

           System.IO.File.Create(archivo);       

            string dest = @"d:\soft";

           //here is the problem
            System.IO.File.Copy(archivo, dest, true);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i solve this problem???

Comment: `System.IO.File.Create(archivo);` is returning a FileStream which you don't `.dispose` of, so the file is still open when you do the copy.  Pay attention to what methods return and how to properly clean up after them

Comment: and you dont need to do Create anyway

Answer (score 7):

The `File.Create()` method creates a file and returns a `FileStream` object to the file (see the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx)). So, if you're not going to use that file stream, then you need to close it before you can access the file:

```
System.IO.File.Create(archivo).Close();
```

Or, since `FileStream` implements `IDisposable`, you can put it in a `using` block, which will close and dispose of it for you:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(archive))
{ 
    // do something with the file stream here if you need to
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST LETS SEE WHAT CAUSED THIS PROBLEM?**

The error message is pretty clear: you're trying to access a file, and it's not accessible because another process (or even the same process) is doing something with it (and it didn't allow any sharing).

You need to include pattern  that will also ensure that the file won't be left open in case of exceptions (it may be the reason the file is in use: something went wrong, and no one closed it;).

When I said you need to implement pattern fortunately `FileStream` implements `IDisposable`, so it's easy to wrap all your code inside a using statement:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(archive)) {
    // do your operations with your files in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers
This worked for me:

```
...
 var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(archivo);
 fileStream.Close();
...
```